# Doctrine MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

Estoy intentando instalar el ODM de Doctrine para MongoDB a través de Composer y recibo el muy famoso error de que me falta la extensión mongo para php

> **Problem 1**
>       - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb 1.4.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.4.0].
>       - doctrine/mongodb 1.4.0 requires ext-mongo ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.

Al hacer un phpinfo(); veo que la extensión se carga correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no se ve la imagen :(

Comment: Sep, creo que hay un problema con el servidor porque yo no veo ninguna imagen en toda la web.

Comment: puedes probar subiendo la imagen a otro servicio online

Comment: hmmm una posibilidad es que tengas `mongo.so` cargado en el `php.ini` de `php-fpm`, pero no en la línea de comando de PHP. Haz `php -m` para listar los módulos cargados en ese `php.ini`.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Estoy viendo que desde la linea de comandos también se carga.

Comment: Te iba a preguntar si era PHP7 pero claramente es la 5.6, o no?

Comment: Si, es la 5.6. Al principio pensé que es cosa de doctrine pero al intentar instalar otro ODM me salta lo mismo. La verdad es que siempre me da dolores de cabeza la instalación de mongo. Intenté también la opción de crearme un box de vagrant y phpuppet y esa opción tampoco me funciona. No se que hacer.

Comment: No será un bug en composer? Qué pasa si corres `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`? (solo para probar, es muy precaria esa salida)

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer Doctrine y muchas de las librerías que he probado utilizan los métodos de mongo.so y por esto al cargar mongodb.so, no funciona.

Los métodos cambian de una extensión a otra como se puede ver abajo:

> MongoClient() se convierte en \MongoDB\Client()
>    MongoCollection() se convierte en \MongoDB\Collection()

Para instalar el paquete antiguo: **sudo pecl install mongo** en vez de **sudo pecl install mongodb**

También es importante integrar mongo.so dentro del **php.ini** que corresponde al CLI: **/etc/php5/cli/php.ini**

Otra cosa que me pasaba y de la que no me di cuenta era que monté un BOX de Vagrant en el cual instalé LAMP y MongoDB. Ese box lo tenía sincronizado con la carpeta del IDE para así ver los cambios que hacía. Cuando necesitaba instalar una librería, iba a la terminal de PhpStorm en la ruta esa carpeta sincronizada y ejecutaba "Composer update" pero sin darme cuenta que la búsqueda de dependencias la iba hacer basándose en la configuración de mi PHP Local y no del Virtual Box.